# insert excel sheet to sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel

The company that I work in has a new project. two of the employees will visit each store to record some information. The project is simple, We just want to insert that data, which has been collected by the two employee, to a sql database.

Unfortunately, the two employees will just have a laptop, which is offline. So, I can't use a synchronization technique to insert the data.

My solution is to allow the two employee to write the data in an excel sheet and then I try to find a way to insert that excel sheet into the sql database.

#### My question

is it possible to insert the excel sheet into the sql database?

is there any better solutions please?

#### Note

The database is very very simple, it is just a one table with three columns. `ID`, `StoreName`, and `StoreProductsNumber`

Comment: why you are not trying to upload csv file it is much easier to parse the file parameters

Comment: the excel file is the csv file. so what is your point please? I didn't get you. I need to have the database because I will use it in another place later on

Comment: Which database are you using. If you are using SSMS (SQL server Management Studio) then you can use import Export Wizard that's built into it. This is the most easy way.

Comment: @GouriShankarAechoor yes I am using sql server 2008 r2. I didn't know about this feature. great I will try to search for it

Answer (score 1):

Or you can schedule query like this to run on server and auto sync:

```
INSERT INTO database..table(ID,StoreName,StoreProductsNumber)
SELECT 
1 AS ID,
LTRIM(RTRIM([StoreName])),
LTRIM(RTRIM([StoreProductsNumber])),
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\folder\excelfile.xls','select * from [sheet1$]')
```

Comment: in your solution, I might end up inserting the same row many times and there will be rows that don't be insterted at all right?

Comment: @user2208349 you can customize the query...you can test if exist the row and if not exists to insert the row.... you can add this in stored procedure and run on the server using service broker or other mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
public string GetDataTableOfExcel(string file_path)
        {

                using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
                {
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    string Import_FileName = Server.MapPath(file_path);
                    //Import_FileName = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(file_path);
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(Import_FileName);
                    if (fileExtension == ".xlsx")
                        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_FileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'";
                    using (OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand())
                    {
                        comm.CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet1$]";
                        comm.Connection = conn;
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                        {
                            da.SelectCommand = comm;
                            da.Fill(dt);
                                                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Now Your Data in DataTable. You can create insert query from datatable's data.

file_path is excel file's full path with directory name.

Answer (score 0):

Through import functionality of SQL server u can achieve it...

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using Import/Export tool. I will try and add a few stwps that can help you through the process.

1. Using SSMS, In the Object Explorer pane, right click on the database > Tasks > Import
2. Select Data Source as Microsoft Excel and Click on Browse to search and select your excel file. Fill the appropriate fields and click next
3. Destination will be populated as you invoked the tool from the target DB. Click Next
4. Select copy data from one or more tables or vies radio button and click next
5. Now select the Excel Tab that contains the required data and under the source and select the target table from the Destination column. Click on Edit mapping and verify if the columns are mapped to the correct destination tables. Click Next
6. Click finish to run the package and load data into SQL Server

You could also be interested in viewing this video that talks about the exact same thing.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GG2N2iI0W3M

Hope this helps.